# React hooks, one hook for each state value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am fairly new to Hooks and am very interested in using it for future projects/work. I am curious to learn more about what are the best practices in terms of using hooks for a component with many different states. As far as I know, for each state value, you would you use the `useState` hook.

Let's say for example we have a class based component with this state:

```
this.state = {
   state1: 0,
   state2: '',
   state3: false,
   state4: [],
   state5: {},
   state6: null
}
```

If I were to convert this using hooks... would best practices be to use `useState` for each state (a total of 6 `useState`) or is there a better way?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With my option, I think the best practice is:

```
   const [state1, setState1] = useState(0)
   const [state2, setState2] = useState('')
   const [state3, setState3] = useState(false)
   const [state4, setState4] = useState([])
   const [state5, setState5] = useState({})
```

Because each state local that you want to control is difference type. And you could control each variable more flexible.

But if you want to do with your case, you can do like that:

```
   const [state, setState] = useState({
       state1: 0,
       state2: ''
       state3: false
   })
```

And when update state1 and state2:

```
   setState({
      ...state,
      state1: 1,
      state2: "yada"
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

All previous answers are correct, but you should also consider how and when you states update. For example if you have

```
const [a, setA] = React.useState('a')
const [b, setB] = React.useState('b')
```

if you **always** call `setA` and `setB` at the same time then you can probalby refactor it to

```
const [ab, setAB] = React.useState({a: 'a', b: 'b})
```

so it is easier to update together.

Otherwise having mutiple state is ok.

Here is a more detailed article from the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Its totally up to you. In my opinion you could do

```
const [state1, updateState1] = useState(0);
```

and repeat for all as you have suggested.

OR

Place all the states in one object and update as necessary

```
const [state, updateState] = useState({state1: 0, state2:''});
```

In this case, to update any item in the state object (e.g state1), you do something like

```
updateState({...state, state1: "new value"})
```